# Side-by-side divs in a WordPress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

[HTML](http://www.guestvibe.com/wordpress/)

[CSS of child theme](http://www.guestvibe.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/guestvibe/style.css)

CSS of parent theme can be found in the directory www.guestvibe.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zincious/css/ and are called:

- admin
- color
- layout
- ie
- navigation
- pagination
- required
- slideshow
- typography

I know this sort of positioning question has been done to death but I'm finding it difficult because of the nature of editing an existing theme.

Essentially, I'd like to position #left and #right next to each other within #featured, but #body below it is giving me problems. Currently, #right is found inside the blue, stripy #body.

My attempt is commented out in the child CSS, but that only caused more havoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following definitions:

```
#left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
#body {
    clear: left;
}
```

Of course, you can make #left and #right whatever dimensions you'd like. I just made them 50% for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but it messes with the div behind it (http://www.guestvibe.com/wordpress/). Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: What's the div's identifier and what should it look like?

Comment: Use the `overflow: auto` rule on the parent div. That will allow it to "contain" the floated items.